# Emoji flag not showing full color in html

Tags: javascript, html, emoji

```js
// Getting the country code and name from the user's IP
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
    $("#flag").html(response.emoji_flag + ' ' + response.country_name);
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="response">
    <div id="flag"></div>
</pre>
```

What I see is

[image]

I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu and have previously been able to see full color emojis on other sites.

The above prints our the two letters of the flag but I want to show the full color flag.

Like

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: It shows the entire flag for me. Is is not what you want ?

Comment: What operating system are you using`?

Comment: For me also shows the entire flag. It should be a problem in your network. Firewall issue ?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on google chrome linux

Comment: What distro?  Different distributions have different default font installations.  Also, please include this information in your question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be way easier to use the provided graphic of the flag instead of emoji? Emojis are nowhere near consistent

Comment: I've included the details in my question. I'm looking to reduce the number of file downloads when the page loads.